# Bank statement translation for Switzerland

Tags: schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds, translations

I am traveling to Switzerland for a competition. The problem is my bank statement consists of my local language, except for the header which is in english.

Do I need a full translation to english or is the version with my local language enough?

Comment: What country are you in? What "local language" are your bank documents in? What does the website of the local Swiss embassy say with regard to if a translation is needed?

Comment: If you're applying for your visa at a local embassy, they will be familiar with the local language and documents and are unlikely to require translations.

Comment: Why you want translation in English? Official languages in Switzerland are French, German, Italian and Romansh.